# iPhone game. 2x issues with iPad3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Running with an issue with an iPhone game that is dropping the frame rate drastically on the iPad3 but not the iPad2.

When 2x is hit on the iPad2 it just zooms and works as before.
On the iPad3 on hitting the 2x button the frame rate drops dramatically.

Retina iPhones have been fine.

Any information would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: We need more information. Can you tell us a bit about what the program renders, whether you have an iPad version, versions of the iPhone that you tested on, etc.

Comment: Also, have you tried using Instruments to profile your application so you can see where the processing time is being spent

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because on the new iPad, retina iPhone apps are actually correctly displayed at their retina resolution (960 x 640) when the iPad is set to 2x. On the previous generation of iPad, when scaled to 2x it still used the non-retina graphics.

As a result, you're seeing performance loss because on the new iPad it's actually using retina graphics instead of just upscaling.